# Understanding Complex Fractions (eg, $\;8/(1/4)\;$) without Simplification

Tags: arithmetic, education, fractions

Normal teachings for thinking about fractions like 4/8 or 8/4 goes something like:

Use the denominator to tell you the amount of equally sized parts in a whole, and use the numerator to tell you the amount of those equally sized parts selected. Cool.

Often this approach to thinking about fractions is accompanied by visualizations of pizza or collections of rectangles. No simplification is required for a result.

But, when you have a complex fraction such as 8/(1/4), the teaching above becomes very difficult to apply and incorrect results are common (at least for me).

Every teaching I find on this says to simplify the problem first and then solve using the normal teaching above. But, one might ask whether simplification is **required** before applying the normal teaching, and if so…why? Can we apply the normal teaching for thinking about complex fractions, without simplifying? Perhaps the normal teaching only works when the numerator is greater than or equal to 1?

Comment: What's wrong with asking how many quarter-pizzas in 8 pizzas? This is the correct model and gives you the correct answer.

Comment: Or you can ask: $8$ pizzas is $\frac{1}{4}$ of what pizza order?

Comment: Also see *partitive* vs. *quotitive* models of division: [short video](https://youtu.be/xnXu-DXEAbQ).

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe, thanks for the comment! The model you reference seems to rely on the notion of dividing the numerator by the denominator, but this line of thinking doesn’t appear to be necessary for the “normal teaching” I referenced. If I have 8/4, I know that a whole is based on 4 equal parts and I need eight of those equal parts, which is equivalent to 2 wholes. Here, the core idea does not seem to rely on dividing the numerator by the denominator.

Comment: @TymaGaidash, that model and the one from Sammy above both make sense to me but seem to steer away from the model of thinking that I referred to as “normal teachings”. The question I have hinges on reusing/extending the normal model from when kids first learn fractions and applying it to complex fractions.

Comment: Why should what you call "normal teaching" extend to a situation it wasn't intended to cover?

Comment: @SammyBlack, yeah I think I may have done a poor job explaining my question. I’ll give it some more thought to see whether there is more I can add to clarify.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thanks for the question. I called it “normal teaching”because...well I just needed to give it a reference name. But, also because it seems very common as a way kids are initially taught to think about fractions. If someone told me that the normal teaching should be reserved for certain types of fractions (albeit the most common ones), then that would be enlightening. That said, it is a little unsatisfying to be told to just simplify and proceed as usual. Could we still solve the problem as usual without simplifying, though more complex it may be?

Comment: What you can do depends on what you allow yourself to do. If "normal teaching" interprets a four in the denominator as dividing a pizza into four slices, then interpret a $1/4$ in the denominator as multiplying a pizza into four pizzas.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I like your suggestion here about what I allow myself to do. I suppose my confidence in doing so is limited by my mathematical maturity, which leads me to stack exchange :-). Good response, one that I will give some more thought. Thanks!

Comment: [Composite or compound fraction](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/23302/372) better name, since `complex fraction' suggests that it contains $i$ somewhere.

Comment: Have you reached any conclusions, Saiya?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, that is awesome of you for asking! During the work week I get a few minutes before bed to jot down some thoughts on how I believe all of this comes together. I think this weekend I will have an opportunity to make a dent in documenting my current understanding. I actually planned on sending that documentation over to you for comment, so it’s funny that you reached back out! Ultimately the idea is to help reduce confusion for my children, so there may be some parts that are painfully obvious.One thing about teaching kids, their questions challenge your understanding of the world.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I wrote some thoughts down but I am unsure as to how to share them with you directly. Do you know of a way to send a message just to you thru stack exchange?

Comment: I'm not sure whether that can be done. There may be a way to open a "chatroom" and limit membership to yourself and the one person you want to talk to, I'm not sure. But I'd rather that all thoughts on m.se questions be shared with everyone on m.se, so I'd rather you communicate here, out in the open.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, roger on all of that. To avoid upsetting the moderators, I better try to present more of an answer than what could feel like a discussion. I’ll spend some more time with my write up to see what I can do to move it away from a discussion and towards an answer.